# Can't compile style.scss with sass-maven-plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, sass, maven-2

I would like to use sass-maven-plugin to compile some `SASS Template style.scss` into `css style.css`. I have added the plugin to my pom.xml build.plugins as it is descriped [here](http://developer.jasig.org/projects/sass-maven-plugin/1.1.0/plugin-info.html). My `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>scss</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>scss</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.4</source>
          <target>1.4</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

<!--       To use the plugin goals in your POM or parent POM -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jasig.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sass-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>

   <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>

  </build>


</project>
```

I run the project with eclipse (right mouseclick on the project -> run as -> run Configuration -> and give as `Goals : sass:update-stylesheets`

eclipse prints the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jasig.maven:sass-maven-plugin:1.1.0:update-stylesheets (default-cli) on project scss: The parameters 'resources' for goal org.jasig.maven:sass-maven-plugin:1.1.0:update-stylesheets are missing or invalid
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add configuration to the plugin to tell it where the files to compile are and where to put the compiled files.

See resources in  http://developer.jasig.org/projects/sass-maven-plugin/1.1.1/update-stylesheets-mojo.html